# Count the number of absent in different sheet excel

Tags: excel

I have 6 worksheets and each containing names of workers. The first sheet just picks data from the other five sheets each representing a week day. The other five sheets contains names of workers which is in a column A, their working hours in column B and column C is whether they are absent or not. I want a way to collect information to the first sheet such that there will be a column that will count the number of days a worker has being absent.

When a worker is absent it is marked "absent" else it is left blank.

Can I use it with VLOOKUP included?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from the first sheet and one of the five sheets?

Comment: To access any data a different sheet, just reference the sheet name along with the cel:  =sheetName!C18

Comment: Also, what is marked in the absent column to represent if they are absent? An "x"? "Y"? "yes"? Is there anything in the column if they are present (like "N" or "No" for not absent)?

Comment: Please respond to the comments. You need to some kind of `COUNTA()` or `IF()` function that reaches across all 5 sheets.

Comment: When a worker is absent it is marked "absent" else it is left blank.

Comment: I've posted a very thorough answer. If it's helpful, please clean up your question a bit and I will upvote it for you. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a "=COUNTIFS(criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2,etc.)" 
statement which might look something like: "=COUNTIFS(WorkerNameRange,WorkerName,AbsentColumn,AbsentIndicator)"
or
"=COUNTIFS(ColumnA,WorkerName,ColumnC,AbsentIndicator)"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you didn't provide a lot of information, so here is my best answer based off of some made up sample data.

We will use `3` workers, `George`, `Bob`, and `Steve`. George works `8` hours/day, Bob `6` hours/day, and Steve `4` hours/day. So this is what I assume the `Monday` sheet would look like

**Monday**

`Bob` and `Steve` both missed work (rough weekend), so we won't count their hours on the `Total` sheet. We will also count this as `1` absent for both.

```
Worker  Hours   Absent
George  8   
Bob     6       absent
Steve   4       absent
```

**Tuesday**

`Tuesday` is similar to `Monday` except that only `Steve` was absent.

```
Worker  Hours   Absent
George  8   
Bob     6       
Steve   4       absent
```

**Total Sheet**

We will assume that no one was absent for the rest of the week. So `George` should have gotten in `40` hours with 0 days absent. `Bob` missed a day, so he only got in `4*6=24` hours. `Steve` missed two days, so his hours will be `3*4=12`. Bob will have `1` absent and `Steve` will have `2`.

```
Worker  Hours   Days Absent
George  40      0
Bob     24      1
Steve   12      2
```

To sum up the hours they were present, we can use the following formula in the `Hours` column on the `Total` sheet.

```
=SUMIFS(Monday!$B$2:$B$4,Monday!$A$2:$A$4,Total!A2,Monday!$C$2:$C$4,"")+SUMIFS(Tuesday!$B$2:$B$4,Tuesday!$A$2:$A$4,Total!A2,Tuesday!$C$2:$C$4,"")+SUMIFS(Wednesday!$B$2:$B$4,Wednesday!$A$2:$A$4,Total!A2,Wednesday!$C$2:$C$4,"")+SUMIFS(Thursday!$B$2:$B$4,Thursday!$A$2:$A$4,Total!A2,Thursday!$C$2:$C$4,"")+SUMIFS(Friday!$B$2:$B$4,Friday!$A$2:$A$4,Total!A2,Friday!$C$2:$C$4,"")
```

What this does is uses a series of [`SUMIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) functions to check each day if the name matches and if they were absent. If they weren't absent, it adds their hours to the total. If they were absent, it does nothing. So we get the correct hour totals. We could just count the absents and then do some math with the number of days absent, but I don't know if you have people who might work different hours different days (e.g. `4` hours `Monday`, `6` hours `Tuesday`, etc.)

To count the hours, we will use a simple [`COUNTA()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/counta-HP005209027.aspx) function.

```
=COUNTA(Monday!C2,Tuesday!C2,Wednesday!C2,Thursday!C2,Friday!C2)
```

This counts all cells in that workers `Absent` columns that are not blank. This allows you flexibility to use any mark for absent as long as blank means "not absent".

There are other ways this spreadsheet could be made more robust with [`Table` formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-an-excel-table-HA010013769.aspx), but I will leave it up to you to do the research.